# How to force google chrome to prefer h264/mp4 over other codecs or container formats

Tags: google-chrome

As the title says, is there a way to force chrome to prefer h264 over vp8/vp9 or other codecs? Or can i define a codec priority list somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension named [h264ify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/h264ify/aleakchihdccplidncghkekgioiakgal).

It will force youtube videos to be played in H.264 codec, over vp8/vp9.